# How to keep an image entirely within a div and still allow it to snap up a row in a fluid grid layout?

Tags: html, css

My images keep overlapping the borders of my div boxes. I have found that `float:none` causes the image to be constrained within the div nicely but then the divs will no longer sit side by side. If I set back to `float:left` they snap up fine. Has anybody got another method to get the image to stay entirely within the div that doesn't involve `float`?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Yes of course but I wasn't sure what code folk would need to see. The boilerplate.css and/or the Fluid Grid.css?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson, as you will see in the above comments this is already in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HMTL:

```
<div>
<img src="something.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

div img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It is a fluid grid so I don't feel the px dimensions would be a good idea. What does the `alt=""` do?

Comment: @SimonElder the `alt` tag is good, you should always put content in there so that search engines can index the images, it is used in SEO. As for the `px`, that was just an example. you can put any dimensions you like.

Comment: I see now, yes the image divs are already in this html format `<div id="ArtboxTwo"><a href="callback.html"><img src="Images/life insurance questionnaire-BnqL.jpg" alt="Quote"></a></div>` and the defaukt boilerplate.css has `img {
 border: 0;
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
 vertical-align: middle;
 max-width: 100%;
}` If I then add the `width: 100%` property the images do indeed fit entirely within the divs but unfortunately it also effects my nav button image divs too so I need to find a way to just effect individual divs. Thanks though @VaMoose

Comment: @SimonElder Then just apply a different `ID` to one of the elements, ie: target the nav's specifically, or the image specifically if it is one instance.

Also, you should never have spaces between your code's file names, so the `life insurance questionnaire-BnqL.jpg` should infact be: `life%20insurance%20questionnaire-BnqL.jpg`

Comment: Hi gain @VaMoose, sorry I'm being a bit of a thicko noob but I can't work out how to change the rule just for the one `ID` I've tried typing something in the ID box but it is still effected by the CSS for images globally.

Comment: @SimonElder when you target the `ID` use `#` in the css before the ID